# How to attach the Xml file in Soap-UI

Tags: java, web-services, soapui

I have plugged-in SoapUI in Eclipse. I need to Know how to attach the Xml Files in SOAPUI. Pls help me... Thnks in Advance

Regards
Michael-aes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the request in SoapUI
2. In the `Request Properties`, make sure that `Enable MTOM` is set to true
3. Select `Attachments (0)`
4. Add an attachment and make sure that an element in your request references that attachment.

http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/adding-headers-and-attachments.html (2. Attachments and Inline Files)